# Does the benefit of the ranger's Natural Explorer feature only activate starting with the second hour of travel in their favored terrain?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, time, travel

The relevant part of the PHB ranger's [Natural Explorer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#NaturalExplorer-295) feature states (emphasis mine):

> **While traveling for an hour or more** in your favored terrain, you
> gain the following benefits:
>
> - Difficult terrain doesn’t slow your group’s travel.
> - Your group can’t become lost except by magical means.
> - [...]

**The way I read this, per RAW, is as follows**:

When a party with a ranger in his favored terrain starts travelling, the first hour of travel the feature is not active and will activate only starting at the 2nd hour of travel.  So they could become lost during the first hour of travel if the navigator fails a Survival check.  If they stop travelling for some reason and resume travel later, they then need to again make Survival checks for the first hour, and then Natural Explorer will kick in again at the 2nd hour.

Am I correctly understanding the Rules as Written for the Natural Explorer feature?

(NOTE: We are not playing with UA rules.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Traveling is present tense

If it said 'after traveling for an hour or more' your conclusion would be correct, but as written it basically means that as long as the journey will last an hour or more the feature is active. Even the first second.

Also the spirit of the ability, is basically just to make it clear that it is non-combat. I believe the travel section of the DMG suggests overland travel to be split into hourly or longer sections, so this fits into that.

Comment: I was tending to this reading also,  but what if you start your daily travel and are stopped by something for the rest of the day (lets say a powerfull storm that makes you hide in a cave for the rest of the day) befalling upon you 30 mins after starting your daily travel..   You did not travel for 1h or more.. So you should not benefit from the natural explorer feature (personnalyt I think it totally sucks the way it is written, but we are very adamant in playing HARD RAW) so how can i make this game mecanic works and still be RAW ?

Comment: @kilrathisly if you are only traveling 30 mins you presumably don't need to be making checks, it is very difficult to get lost in that kind of time unless you are in a maze. But also there is no mention of a time limit, so just because you pause doesn't mean you won't continue the next day, which is still traveling for 1 hour or more. The only thing that would in my opinion stop this feature is when you reach the destination.

Comment: For lack of a better answer, I flagged your answer as good for now,  but coulds you edite the word journey to travel.. there is no such thing in the RAW rules of D&D as a journey in that rule.   It specifically mentions your TRAVEL, not journey (in fact journey is not mentioned anywhere in the TRAVEL mode rules).  By the way  I make navigation checks to get lost every start of an hour in travel mode.  so yes you could get lost in 30 mins of travelling.  this is totally realistic (see below)

Comment: If you ever went to a real wilderness trek in the deep woods you will see quite soon enough that without a compass and an accurate map you will get lost and likely die of exposure. and in a few days not weeks.  I want to bring that gruesome realism to the game, by making the navigator check every hour to see if he gets lost.  with a DC15, without a map and a way of knowing where north is accurately and unneerigly.  they will get lost within a day.  So better get equipped or die in the wilderness   which is totally realistic.

Comment: @KilrathiSly within one day, not within one hour...

Comment: @STT LCU What is within one day ?

Comment: @KilrathiSly you said 'they will get lost within a day'. I underlined that you can get lost within a day, but it'd be absurd for a natural explorer to get lost within one hour.

Comment: @STT LCU,  RAW rules don't make any difference between day or hours,  Merely states that when you travel you can get lost and to be honest it is very realistic to gett lost in a forest without a compass and map or landmarks to navigate.  It happened every year at the deep forest camp we had a few years back.  PPL not used to trekking in wilderness don't understand how easy it is and fast to get lost in a forest.

Comment: @KilrathiSly would a ranger within his favourite environment qualify as someone not used to trek in a wilderness environment? I severely doubt so, and that's why it doesn't make any sense for the DM to trigger the navigation check in the first hour. You, and your table, are however free to do so, and both behaviors are strictly within RAW.

Comment: Yes if he treks for more than 1h.  If he treks for only 30 mins he is as noob as anyone else (I am not making the rule, this is what they wrote we must apply it blindly without common sense, this is how RAW playing is done)

Answer (score 12):

### The DM decides when it's appropriate to check if the party's navigator is lost in the wilderness

Source: *Dungeon Master's Guide*, page 111

Strictly rules as written, it's the DM that decides when to check if the party is lost. If your DM decides that it's opportune (and appropriate) that the party is lost from the start, then the Ranger's Natural Explorer ability doesn't trigger.

***Now, the following is my own personal consideration:***

It doesn't make any sense to me to "be lost" without magical interference already at the start of the journey, and it's also very hard to lose yourself in the first hour if you're even moderately proficient with being outdoors, which for most Rangers inside their favorite terrain is definitely the case. I'd say that this could be a passive survival DC 10 check.

Lastly, penalizing the Ranger on a ribbon feature that already sees the light of day very rarely would leave a sour taste in my mouth, so I'd recommend not going down the route of getting lost in the first hour.

Comment: I see what you are saying but we are a group that play STRICT and HARD RAW.  even if it is dumb or irrealistic we just want the game mecanic to play like almost a computer game.  (we have fun doing RP so we don't care realism or logic of a rule, we care about following the rules to the letter as they are written.  Unfortunately Jeremy Crawford did not shed light on this one.